# Взаимодействие сайта с программой на java

Tags: java, сеть, веб-программирование

Доброе время суток. Имеется программа на java - её функционал маленький - прием файлом по сети (т.е. открывает порт, ждет подключения и грузит нужный файл на сервер). Как можно реализовать подключение к программе с сайта и загрузку файла непосредственно с сайта? В сторону каких технологий и методов смотреть?

Comment: Ребят, еще варианты реализации есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мне кажется у вас есть два варианта:
1) простенький апплет который будет коннектится к вашей проге-серверу
2) вместо сервера (и/или вместе с ним) вешаете простенький веб-сервер. который будет предоставлять нужный вам функционал. веб сервер сможет работать напрямую с файловой системой компьютера или как надстройка над вашей программой

Comment: @jmu, а если появится нужда в усовершенствовании этой программы, добавления дополнительного функционала (например системы авторизации), какой метод более подходит для реализации а данной ситуации?

Comment: мне больше нравится вариант с веб-сервером. там можно запилить приличное ГУИ + сесии, пользователей

Answer (score 2):

Весь вопрос состоит в том как работает эта Java прога.

1. Если она сидит напротив открытого порта и ждет, то фактически она уже выступает в качестве сервера - тогда надо запулить на ее адрес и порт то что она ждет
2. Если же ее надо удаленно запускать - тут сложнее. Полюбас придется писать некую сервисную оболочку над этой прогой, ну чтобы удаленный сайт смог до нее достучаться - наружу должен смотреть некий сервис/сервер. Реализовать это можно массой разных способов, ну самый такой модный наверное через веб-сервис. Есть еще попроще способ [Java Network Launch Protocol - он же Java Web Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) - если совсем кратко способ запуска приложений через сеть.

Comment: @Barmaley, спасибо. Запускается локально, как сервер. Удаленный запуск не нужен. Эта программа является сервером, так же есть клиент, но нужен что то типа web клиент. Из предложенных Вами вариантов - 1й

Comment: А просто например на php с помощью функции fsockopen реализовать нельзя?

Comment: наверно еще проще будет через аплет заливку сделать....  если ты знаешь пхп - попробуй прикрутить